# Is it possible to apply sprintf to format a HERE DOCUMENT string?

Tags: perl

I'd like to embed tokens inside a HERE DOCUMENT and then use `(s)printf` on the final string to replace these tokens with actual values. The reason is: This makes it much easier to build a HERE DOCUMENT with some parts of it that are varying.

To explain, here is how I would do this in Python. From the small example below it will be more clear what I am trying to do. In Python `r"""` is similar to Perl `<<EOT`, i.e. it builds multi-line raw string. The string has to end with `"""` similar to Perl ending with `EOT`.

```
s=r"""
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{%(title)s}
\date{%(date)s}
  some text
\end{document}"""

print s % {"title": "My report","date": "1/1/2016"}
```

The above prints

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{My report}
\date{1/1/2016}
  some text
\end{document}
```

Notice that the `%(title)` and `%(date)` were replaced at the end by values given. This is very similar to doing `sprintf('%s',some_string)`, but here it is applied to the raw string itself. This is very handy and makes building raw string very easy.

Here is an [MWE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/MWE) in Perl, but I am stuck on the last part, and I also do not know how to do the whole thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my $title = "My report";
my $date  = "1/1/2016";

my $s =<<'EOT';
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{%(title)s}
\date{%(date)s}
  some text
\end{document}
EOT

print($s);   #how to format this in order to replace %title and %date
             #emmbeded in $s with the values above? is it possible?
```

Make sure `EOT` is leftmost and has no spaces after it.

I do not know if this is even possible in Perl. But I think if it is possible in Python, it should also be possible in Perl?

Please note that I can't use interpolation in HERE DOCUMENT, i.e. `<<"EOT"` will not work for many reasons, and must use non interpolation HERE DOCUMENT. So something like this will not work for me:

```
my $s =<<"EOT";
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{$title}
\date{$date}
  some text
\end{document}
EOT
```

Comment: Curious… why won't interpolation work?

Comment: @vol7ron interpolation will not work at all. Try the example I posted with `"EOT"` instead of `'EOT'`, the problem is Latex using `$` itself, and also uses `\\` for all its commands. Interpolation will get in the way and generate many errors.

Comment: It should work, you just have to escape certain symbols.

Comment: @vol7ron "you just have to escape certain symbols" but the whole point of this, is not to do that!. This is raw text and I do not want to keep escaping things in it each time. If I copy the raw text out, I want it to remain the same and not have to remove the escape slashed added again.

Comment: So in your LaTex you're using a variable that your LaTex is not processing?  Is it embedded in your Perl, or is it an actual tex file?

Comment: @vol7ron I am using Perl to generate the Latex. There are few places in the Latex code that I need to plugin some values for (like title, date, author, etc...) But the bulk of the Latex code should remain as is, unmodified. This way if I want later to use it outside of Perl, the changes are very minimal. I can copy it out. If I have to modify the Latex code greatly by escaping it everywhere, then this whole process will not work at all. I am trying to minimize any changes to the Latex code, that is why Interpolation will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, there are a few options; which I'll only address two of the simpler methods to implement (i.e., `printf`/`sprintf` and regex).

1. ### `printf`/`sprintf`

   If you know the order of the placeholders, you can use the correct templating variables `%s` for string and insert your values using variables in the `printf` call.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   use strict;
   use warnings;

   my $title = "My report";
   my $date  = "1/1/2016";

   my $s =<<'EOT';
   \documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
   \begin{document}
   \title{%s}
   \date{%s}
     some text
   \end{document}
   EOT

   printf( $s, $title, $date);
   ```
2. ### Regex

   Using regex, you could look for the literal string and replace that with some desired value (a variable).

   #### Simple Replace

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   use strict;
   use warnings;

   my $title = "My report";
   my $date  = "1/1/2016";

   my $s     = <<'EOT';
   \documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
   \begin{document}
   \title{$title}
   \date{$date}
     some text
   \end{document}
   EOT

   $s =~ s/\$(title|date)/"\$$1"/eeg;            # ee is important and so is wrapping the replacement pattern in a string

   print $s;
   ```

   #### Hash Table Replace

   You could make the process even more automated/flexible by using a replace hash. This helps to automatically generate the regex pattern and use the hash table to retrieve the respective value for the replacement. The benefit is you could add more-or-less variables to your hash, without having to touch the regex again (the pattern doesn't get any larger).

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   use strict;
   use warnings;

   my $replace = {
     title => q{My report},
     date  => q{1/1/2016}
   };

   my $s = <<'EOT';
   \documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
   \begin{document}
   \title{$title}
   \date{$date}
     some text
   \end{document}
   EOT

   $s =~ s/\$(@{[ join '|', keys %$replace ]})/$replace->{$1}/g;

   print $s;
   ```

   #### Regex Caveats

   There are however many caveats. For instance, word-wrapping could be a problem depending on where the variable breaks - the regex is not set up to look for that. A bigger concern is if you actually wanted the literal string '$title' or '$date' to appear in the generated document (after executing the [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) code), the regex would have replaced it with some value. You'll have to determine which works best for you.

   Generally, in templating/parsing there isn't a one-line answer and it usually involves multiple statement process for various reasons (e.g., performance, maintainability, logic/complexity, or simply because it couldn't work otherwise).

Comment: the regex trick is very nice! But named sprintf is still a little more clear I feel. Thanks.

Comment: @GrantMcLean yeah a template library like Template.pm or Template::Toolkit could be useful.  The big reason I didn't include one is there's a learning curve and it seems like the OP wanted something a little more straightforward and closer to printf.  It is a good suggestion though.

Answer (score 4):

You may be over-complicating things.  Yes Perl has `sprintf` and yes you can specify the format string using a heredoc, but it would be much easier to just use variable interpolation:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my $title = "My report";
my $date  = "1/1/2016";

my $s =<<"EOT";
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{$title}
\date{$date}
  some text
\end{document}
EOT

print $s;
```

Note, I changed your single quotes around the `EOT` to double quotes.
Normally you can just include a variable name in a double-quoted string, e.g.: `"$title"` but if you need to follow that with a literal letter, number or underscore, then simply wrap curly braces around the variable name: `"${title}_word"`.

To answer the question as asked, you could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my $title = "My report";
my $date  = "1/1/2016";

my $s =<<'EOT';
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{%s}
\date{%s}
  some text
\end{document}
EOT

printf($s, $title, $date);
```

Perl's `sprintf` doesn't support named placeholders.

Edit: As @Nasser pointed out in a later comment my first example won't work as written, because changing from single to double quoting means that the backslashes need to be doubled up and any literal `$` characters in the string would also need to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

Perl's `sprintf` doesn't support named parameters, however the [`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) module was designed precisely for this sort of thing. It has been applied to LaTeX in many projects, and the [`Template::Plugin::Latex`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Plugin::Latex) module was written to facilitate this even further

Here's an example of using the basic module to format the sample data in the question. Note that the usual use case has the template stored in a separate text file as the `process` method will take a filename as its first parameter. But it will also take an open file handle (so you can use the `DATA` file handle if you wish) or a simple string if it is passed by reference, as here

The module is highly configurable, and the embedded directives form a comprehensive language, comparable to PHP, that allow templates to be written that match pretty much any circumstance

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Template;

my %vars = (
  title => 'My report',
  date  => '1/1/2016',
);

my $template =<<'EOT';
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{[% title %]}
\date{[% date %]}
  some text
\end{document}
EOT

my $tt = Template->new;
$tt->process(\$template, \%vars);
```

#### output

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{My report}
\date{1/1/2016}
  some text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Example:

```
printf <<'TEMPLATE',

   %-20s    $%6.2f
   %-20s    $%6.2f
   %-20s    $%6.2f
   --------------------    -------
   TOTAL                   $%6.2f

TEMPLATE
    "Cheeseburger", 3.29,
    "Medium fries", 1.99,
    "Large soda", 1.69,
    3.29 + 1.99 + 1.69;
```

In this example note the comma after the first `TEMPLATE`. You could omit it there and put it after the second template, at the beginning of a new line. Or you could put the other arguments to `printf` after the first `TEMPLATE`. Or you can mix it up -- not recommended, but you can

```
printf <<'TEMPLATE', "Cheeseburger", 3.29, "Medium fries"

   %-20s    $%6.2f
   %-20s    $%6.2f
   %-20s    $%6.2f
   --------------------    -------
   TOTAL                   $%6.2f

TEMPLATE
    , 1.99,
    "Large soda", 1.69,
    3.29 + 1.99 + 1.69;
```

But as Grant McLean suggests, it is saner to put your template into a variable first -- created with a heredoc if it makes sense, but to make the `printf/sprintf` call itself look simple.